# How to find the angle of deformation in Ansys APDL?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling, finite-element-method, ansys, structural-analysis

After solving my problem in APDL, and started doing some post-processing, I want to find how much the deformed shape has rotated (i.e. the maximum angle the furthest node has made comparing with the original unreformed shape), I'm doing 2D analysis, is this exactly what is shown as, z-component of rotation, or there is other thing I need to know?  and in which units, deg or rad?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get the structural rotation around X axis for a given node (N) using the next APDL command: `*get,Parameter_output,NODE,N,ROT,X`. You can substitute `X` by `Y` or `Z` depending the axis you want reference to.

You can find more information on the *GET command in the Command Reference Manual about this case on page 742.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to define a coordinate using NWPLAN & CSWPLA from 3 nodes, then extract the angles via *GET, par, CDSY, N, ANG, xy for example for THXY rotation.